# I 'd like to stop @KafkaListener after some time

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I would like to stop a App that has a  KafkaListener after some time without receiving messages (eg:2000ms) or  after a specific time has passed since it was first time launched.

The app is a JAva App that loads spring & kafka libs. NOT USING SPRING BOOT

I haven't found examples that worked exactly as this. Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

When Kafka listener container doesn't receive records from the Kafka consumer for some period of time, it emits a `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`:

```
@EventListener
public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You can get more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/_reference.html#idle-containers).